Solving a 2-scheme strip cutting problem with python
I am studying a scientific paper about integer programming formulations for a 2-schemes strip cutting problem which arises in the context of corrugated cardboard production and would like to recreate some parts of the solving procedure using python's pulp module.
A corrugator machine produces rectangular items of cardboard in different widths, lengths and quantities. The items cannot be rotated. The machinery has knives which perform longitudinal cuts and two cutters that perform transversal cuts, hence items of either one or at most two different lengths are cut simultaneously. A typical production program consists of many cutting patterns, each of them specifying the (at most two) items to be cut and the number of pieces of each item to be produced. The production of an item size may be partitioned into many cutting patterns.

INPUT:
items = {
    1: {"width": 476, "height": 476, "quantity": 950},
    2: {"width": 450, "height": 455, "quantity": 2000},
    3: {"width": 450, "height": 450, "quantity": 2000},
    4: {"width": 450, "height": 450, "quantity": 2000},
    5: {"width": 405, "height": 405, "quantity": 3120},
    6: {"width": 460, "height": 460, "quantity": 2400},
}

# production parameters
PAPER_WIDTH = 1400  # selected paper width in [mm] (paper length is infinite)
WASTE_TOLERANCE = 0.2  # maximum lateral waste percentage
PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE = 0.1  # production tolerance percentage

OUTPUT: An optimal sequence of 1-schemes and 2-schemes
# i, j - item index
# n1, n2 - number of i, j items which are transversally cut at each operation
# m - paper length used for the particular pattern 
patterns = [
    # (i, n1, j, n2, m)
    (4, 3, None, None, 150), # 1-scheme
    (5, 3, None, None, 421), # 1-scheme
    (2, 2, 6, 1, 455), # 2-scheme
    (6, 1, 3, 2, 450), # 2-scheme
    (6, 3, None, None, 70), # 1-scheme
]

CONSTRAINTS:

objective: minimizing the total waste of the pattern sequence
2-scheme: tuple (i, j, n1, n2, m) with i != j
2-scheme: (1 - WASTE_TOLERANCE) * PAPER_WIDTH <= n1 * widthi + n2 * widthj <= PAPER_WIDTH
1-scheme: tuple (i, n1, m) with i != j
1-scheme: (1 - WASTE_TOLERANCE) * PAPER_WIDTH <= n1 * widthi <= PAPER_WIDTH
quantity: within [quantityi * (1 - PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE), quantityi * (1 + PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE)]

So far I just collected some ideas for the solution. I am not entirely sure if the Problem is solvable with PuLP at all. The scientific paper hints that this problem was solved using CPLEX. I am hoping to get some suggestions which might direct me towards the final result. If I understand correctly I need at least two binary variables which indicate whether a 1-scheme/2-scheme item is included in the pattern. Further two integer variables are required for the number of items that are cut transversally in a pattern. Also there must be a variable which indicates the length of the pattern? I also struggle to formulate the objective function since it requires an expression for both schemes? The constraints are also incomplete. I understand that this kind of problem is a real challenge and am thankful for every hint.
def pulp_2SSCP():
    items = [
        {"width": 476, "height": 476, "quantity": 950},
        {"width": 450, "height": 455, "quantity": 2000},
        {"width": 450, "height": 450, "quantity": 2000},
        {"width": 450, "height": 450, "quantity": 2000},
        {"width": 405, "height": 405, "quantity": 3120},
        {"width": 460, "height": 460, "quantity": 2400},
    ]

    # production parameters
    PAPER_WIDTH = 1400  # selected paper width in [mm]
    WASTE_TOLERANCE = 0.2  # maximum lateral waste percentage
    PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE = 0.1  # production tolerance percentage
    MAX_PATTERNS = 10

    # ranges
    i_range = range(len(items))
    s_range = range(MAX_PATTERNS)

    # VARIABLES
    # whether item `i` is included in cutting pattern `s`
    x = LpVariable.dicts(
        "x",
        [(i, s) for i in i_range for s in s_range],
        cat=LpBinary,
    )

    # whether items `i` and `j` are included in cutting pattern `s`
    y = LpVariable.dicts(
        "y",
        [(i, j, s) for i in i_range for j in i_range for s in s_range],
        cat=LpBinary,
    )

    # number of items `i` that are cut transversally in pattern `s`
    n1 = LpVariable.dicts(
        "n1",
        [(i, s) for i in i_range for s in s_range],
        lowBound=0,
        cat=LpInteger,
    )

    # number of items `j` that are cut transversally in pattern `s` in a two-item pattern
    n2 = LpVariable.dicts(
        "n2",
        [(i, j, s) for i in i_range for j in i_range for s in s_range],
        lowBound=0,
        cat=LpInteger,
    )

    # model
    prob = LpProblem("2SSCP", LpMinimize)

    # objective function
    prob += lpSum(
        PAPER_WIDTH - n1[i, s] * items[i]["width"] for i in i_range for s in s_range
    )
    prob += lpSum(
        items[j]["width"] * n2[i, j, s]
        for i in i_range
        for j in i_range
        for s in s_range
        if i != j
    )

    # constraints
    # 1. Quantity Constraints
    for i in i_range:
        # Single-Item Quantity Constraint
        prob += (
            (1 - PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE) * items[i]["quantity"]
            <= items[i]["quantity"]
            <= (1 + PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE) * items[i]["quantity"]
        )

        # Two-Item Quantity Constraint
        for j in i_range:
            if i != j:
                prob += (
                    (1 - PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE) * items[j]["quantity"]
                    <= items[j]["quantity"]
                    <= (1 + PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE) * items[j]["quantity"]
                )

    # 2. Width Constraints
    for s in s_range:
        for i in i_range:
            prob += (
                (1 - WASTE_TOLERANCE) * PAPER_WIDTH
                <= n1[i, s] * items[i]["width"]
                <= PAPER_WIDTH
            )
            for j in i_range:
                if i != j:
                    prob += (
                        (1 - WASTE_TOLERANCE) * PAPER_WIDTH
                        <= n1[i, s] * items[i]["width"]
                        + n2[i, j, s] * items[j]["width"]
                        <= PAPER_WIDTH
                    )

    prob.solve()


If there are only two patterns, why are there six widths?

The wording might be a little bit confusing since the word pattern and scheme can be used interchangeably in this context. The pattern type can be either a 1-scheme or a 2-scheme. The result consists of an unlimited sequence of patterns which are either a 1-scheme or a 2-scheme. In this example there are only 6 items, but in real world applications it is common to have something between 20 and 40 different items. Hope this makes it a little bit more clear.

Can you cite the paper? I don't see how this could be linear - each pattern has a variable horizontal-count and vertical-count that need to be multiplied to get the number of items.

You might be able to exhaustively enumerate the permutations of items that can fit vertically.

@Reinderien You are probably right with your suggestion of exhaustive permutation. The paper states: "All the variables are generated, corresponding to explicitly enumerating all
feasible patterns. Although this approach may be impractical in general, for real-life
cardboard corrugator instances this does not impose too heavy a penalty since the
total number of patterns is usually quite limited."

The paper I am referring to is called "An integer programming approach for the 2-schemes strip cutting problem with a sequencing constraint". There is also an other paper called "A two-dimensional strip cutting problem with sequencing constraint". Both are about the same topic, but they actually focus on the sequencing constraint of the patterns which would be the next step. To be able to do so you need to calculate the optimal patterns first. Both papers explain in detail how to achieve that theoretically, but I am just not clever enough to apply it in praxis.

As in the comments, unless you get "creative", this is non-linear and LP cannot be applied; to get around this you can run a pre-opt step that exhaustively defines all viable patterns. Our poor little open-source solver considers this a difficult question unless you widen the gap tolerance (or, equivalently, impose a timeout that halts optimisation and doesn't bother reducing the gap as much as it would by default). Doing so is quite safe for these inputs.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pulp

# units. Explicitly write a unit for all input literals. All program variables in
# natural (m) units, among other reasons to keep areas at a reasonable order of magnitude.
M = 1.
MM = 1e-3*M

# production parameters
PAPER_WIDTH = 1400*MM       # selected paper width (paper length is infinite)
WASTE_TOLERANCE = 0.2       # maximum lateral waste percentage
PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE = 0.1  # production tolerance percentage


def make_items() -> pd.DataFrame:
    # n.b.: diagram is cursed, because "height" is horizontal and "width" is vertical. Those terms are maintained here.
    items = pd.DataFrame(
        index=pd.Index(name='item', data=np.arange(start=1, stop=7)),
        data={
            'width':    (476*MM, 450*MM, 450*MM, 450*MM, 405*MM, 460*MM),
            'height':   (476*MM, 455*MM, 450*MM, 450*MM, 405*MM, 460*MM),
            'quantity': (   950,   2000,   2000,   2000,   3120,   2400),
        },
    )
    return items


def make_patterns(items: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # All combinations of items in the bottom and top rows
    patterns = pd.merge(
        left=items[['width', 'height']].reset_index(),
        right=items[['width', 'height']].reset_index(),
        how='cross', suffixes=('_bottom', '_top'),
    )

    # Bottom row is always present in 1-patterns or 2-patterns
    patterns['min_count_v_bottom'] = 1
    patterns['max_count_v_bottom'] = PAPER_WIDTH/patterns['width_bottom']
    any_count = pd.Series(
        name='count_v_bottom',
        data=np.arange(1, 1 + patterns['max_count_v_bottom'].max()),
    ).astype(int)
    patterns = pd.merge(left=patterns, right=any_count, how='cross')
    patterns['total_width_bottom'] = patterns['count_v_bottom']*patterns['width_bottom']
    patterns = patterns[patterns['total_width_bottom'] <= PAPER_WIDTH]

    # Top row is only present in 2-patterns; absence is implied by a 0-count
    patterns['min_count_v_top'] = (
        (
            PAPER_WIDTH*(1 - WASTE_TOLERANCE) - patterns['total_width_bottom']
        ) / patterns['width_top']
    ).clip(0)
    patterns['max_count_v_top'] = (
        PAPER_WIDTH - patterns['total_width_bottom']
    ) / patterns['width_top']
    any_count = pd.Series(
        name='count_v_top',
        data=np.arange(0, 1 + patterns['max_count_v_top'].max()),
    ).astype(int)
    patterns = pd.merge(left=patterns, right=any_count, how='cross')
    patterns = patterns[
        (patterns['count_v_top'] >= patterns['min_count_v_top']) &
        (patterns['count_v_top'] <= patterns['max_count_v_top'])
    ]

    # Remove duplicates within 1-patterns
    is_single = patterns['count_v_top'] == 0
    patterns = pd.concat((
        patterns[~is_single],
        patterns[is_single].drop_duplicates(subset=('item_bottom', 'count_v_bottom')),
    )).sort_index()

    # Subtotals
    patterns['total_width_top'] = patterns['count_v_top']*patterns['width_top']
    patterns['total_width'] = patterns['total_width_bottom'] + patterns['total_width_top']
    patterns['width_waste'] = PAPER_WIDTH - patterns['total_width']

    return patterns


def make_var_names(patterns: pd.DataFrame) -> np.ndarray:
    return patterns[['item_bottom', 'count_v_bottom', 'item_top', 'count_v_top']].values


def make_pattern_vars(patterns: pd.DataFrame, var_names: np.ndarray) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # Variables per pattern (not per item)
    pattern_vars = pd.DataFrame(
        index=patterns.index,
        data={
            'count_h_bottom': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='count_h_bottom', cat=pulp.LpInteger, indices=var_names, lowBound=0,
            ),
            'count_h_top': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='count_h_top', cat=pulp.LpInteger, indices=var_names, lowBound=0,
            ),
            'total_height': pulp.LpVariable.matrix(
                name='total_height', cat=pulp.LpContinuous, indices=var_names,
            ),
        },
    )

    # Replace h_top variables with literal 0 for 1-patterns
    pattern_vars.loc[patterns['count_v_top'] <= 0, 'count_h_top'] = 0

    # Not variables; these are LpAffineExpression
    pattern_vars['total_height_bottom'] = pattern_vars['count_h_bottom']*patterns['height_bottom']
    pattern_vars['total_height_top'] = pattern_vars['count_h_top']*patterns['height_top']
    pattern_vars['waste'] = (  # in m²
        pattern_vars['total_height']*patterns['width_waste']
        + (pattern_vars['total_height'] - pattern_vars['total_height_bottom'])*patterns['total_width_bottom']
        + (pattern_vars['total_height'] - pattern_vars['total_height_top'])*patterns['total_width_top']
    )
    pattern_vars['total_items_bottom'] = pattern_vars['count_h_bottom']*patterns['count_v_bottom']
    pattern_vars['total_items_top'] = pattern_vars['count_h_top']*patterns['count_v_top']
    return pattern_vars


def make_item_vars(
    items: pd.DataFrame,
    patterns: pd.DataFrame,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    item_vars = pd.DataFrame(
        index=items.index,
        data={
            'items_bottom': [
                pulp.lpSum(group['total_items_bottom'])
                for i, group in patterns.groupby('item_bottom')
            ],
            'items_top': [
                pulp.lpSum(group['total_items_top'])
                for i, group in patterns.groupby('item_top')
            ],
        },
    )
    item_vars['prod_error'] = (item_vars['items_bottom'] + item_vars['items_top'])/items['quantity'] - 1

    return item_vars


def make_problem(waste: pulp.LpAffineExpression) -> pulp.LpProblem:
    prob = pulp.LpProblem(name='dual_cutting', sense=pulp.LpMinimize)
    prob.setObjective(waste)
    return prob


def add_constraints(
    prob: pulp.LpProblem,
    items: pd.DataFrame,
    patterns: pd.DataFrame,
    var_names: np.ndarray,
) -> None:
    for (i, row), name in zip(patterns.iterrows(), var_names):
        '''
        Redundant, doesn't help with solution:
        # count_h_bottom*count_v_bottom <= quantity*(1 + tol)
        row['count_h_bottom'].bounds(
            low=0,
            up=items.loc[row['item_bottom'], 'quantity']/row['count_v_bottom']*(1 + PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE),
        )
        if not isinstance(row['count_h_top'], int):
            row['count_h_top'].bounds(
                low=0,
                up=items.loc[row['item_top'], 'quantity']/row['count_v_top']*(1 + PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE),
            )
        '''
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'height_bottom{name}',
            constraint=row['total_height'] >= row['total_height_bottom'],
        )
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'height_top{name}',
            constraint=row['total_height'] >= row['total_height_top'],
        )

    for i, row in items.iterrows():
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'items_lower_{i}',
            constraint=row['prod_error'] >= -PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE,
        )
        prob.addConstraint(
            name=f'items_upper_{i}',
            constraint=row['prod_error'] <= +PRODUCTION_TOLERANCE,
        )


def solve(
    prob: pulp.LpProblem, items: pd.DataFrame, patterns: pd.DataFrame,
    gap_rel: float = 1e-3, time_limit: float = 1., verbose: bool = False,
) -> tuple[pd.DataFrame, pd.DataFrame]:
    prob.solve(solver=pulp.PULP_CBC_CMD(
        timeLimit=time_limit, gapRel=gap_rel, msg=verbose,
    ))
    if prob.status != pulp.LpStatusOptimal:
        raise ValueError(prob.status)

    items = items.map(pulp.value)
    patterns = patterns.map(pulp.value)
    patterns = patterns[patterns['total_height'] > 0].set_index(
        keys=['item_bottom', 'count_v_bottom', 'item_top', 'count_v_top'],
    )
    return items, patterns


def main(verbose: bool = False) -> None:
    items = make_items()
    patterns = make_patterns(items=items)
    n_patterns = len(patterns)

    pd.options.display.width = 200
    pd.options.display.max_columns = None
    pd.options.display.max_rows = None

    if verbose:
        print('All viable patterns:')
        print(patterns)
        print()

    var_names = make_var_names(patterns)
    patterns = pd.concat((
        patterns, make_pattern_vars(patterns=patterns, var_names=var_names),
    ), axis='columns')
    items = pd.concat((
        items, make_item_vars(items=items, patterns=patterns),
    ), axis='columns')

    waste = pulp.lpSum(patterns['waste'])
    prob = make_problem(waste=waste)
    add_constraints(prob=prob, items=items, patterns=patterns, var_names=var_names)

    if verbose:
        print(prob)

    # This gap tolerance works fine and produces waste of ~113 m².
    # In fact, for these inputs, the solver reports the objective lower bound as 112.761 m².
    # Lowering the gap significantly slows solution; we impose a timeout of 1s for demonstration.
    items, patterns = solve(
        prob=prob, items=items, patterns=patterns, verbose=verbose, gap_rel=2e-3,
    )

    if verbose:
        print('Solved items:')
        print(items)
        print()
    else:
        print(f'Waste: {waste.value():.2f} m²')
    print(f'Used {len(patterns)}/{n_patterns} feasible patterns:')

    if verbose:
        print(patterns.T)
    else:
        print(patterns[['count_h_bottom', 'count_h_top']].T.astype(int))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

All viable patterns:
     item_bottom  width_bottom  height_bottom  item_top  width_top  height_top  min_count_v_bottom  max_count_v_bottom  count_v_bottom  total_width_bottom  min_count_v_top  max_count_v_top  \
10             1         0.476          0.476         2      0.450       0.455                   1            2.941176               1               0.476         1.431111         2.053333   
...
     count_v_top  total_width_top  total_width  width_waste  
10             2            0.900        1.376        0.024  


dual_cutting:
MINIMIZE
-0.22657600000000003*count_h_bottom__1_1_2_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_bottom__1_1_3_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_bottom__1_1_4_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_bottom__1_1_5_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_bottom__1_1_6_2_ + -0.45315200000000005*count_h_bottom__1_2_5_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_bottom__2_1_2_2_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_bottom__2_1_3_2_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_bottom__2_1_4_2_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_bottom__2_1_5_2_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_bottom__2_1_6_2_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_1_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_2_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_3_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_4_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_5_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_bottom__2_2_6_1_ + -0.6142500000000001*count_h_bottom__2_3_1_0_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__3_1_2_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__3_1_3_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__3_1_4_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__3_1_5_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__3_1_6_2_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_1_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_2_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_3_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_4_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_5_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__3_2_6_1_ + -0.6075*count_h_bottom__3_3_1_0_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__4_1_2_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__4_1_3_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__4_1_4_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__4_1_5_2_ + -0.2025*count_h_bottom__4_1_6_2_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_1_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_2_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_3_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_4_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_5_1_ + -0.405*count_h_bottom__4_2_6_1_ + -0.6075*count_h_bottom__4_3_1_0_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_1_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_2_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_3_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_4_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_5_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_bottom__5_1_6_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_1_1_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_2_1_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_3_1_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_4_1_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_5_1_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_bottom__5_2_6_1_ + -0.49207500000000004*count_h_bottom__5_3_1_0_ + -0.2116*count_h_bottom__6_1_2_2_ + -0.2116*count_h_bottom__6_1_3_2_ + -0.2116*count_h_bottom__6_1_4_2_ + -0.2116*count_h_bottom__6_1_5_2_ + -0.2116*count_h_bottom__6_1_6_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_1_1_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_2_1_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_3_1_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_4_1_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_5_1_ + -0.4232*count_h_bottom__6_2_6_1_ + -0.6348*count_h_bottom__6_3_1_0_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__1_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__1_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__1_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__1_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__1_1_6_2_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__1_2_5_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__2_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__2_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__2_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__2_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__2_1_6_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_top__2_2_1_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_top__2_2_2_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__2_2_3_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__2_2_4_1_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__2_2_5_1_ + -0.2116*count_h_top__2_2_6_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__3_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__3_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__3_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__3_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__3_1_6_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_top__3_2_1_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_top__3_2_2_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__3_2_3_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__3_2_4_1_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__3_2_5_1_ + -0.2116*count_h_top__3_2_6_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__4_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__4_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__4_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__4_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__4_1_6_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_top__4_2_1_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_top__4_2_2_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__4_2_3_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__4_2_4_1_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__4_2_5_1_ + -0.2116*count_h_top__4_2_6_1_ + -0.45315200000000005*count_h_top__5_1_1_2_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__5_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__5_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__5_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__5_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__5_1_6_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_top__5_2_1_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_top__5_2_2_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__5_2_3_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__5_2_4_1_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__5_2_5_1_ + -0.2116*count_h_top__5_2_6_1_ + -0.40950000000000003*count_h_top__6_1_2_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__6_1_3_2_ + -0.405*count_h_top__6_1_4_2_ + -0.32805000000000006*count_h_top__6_1_5_2_ + -0.4232*count_h_top__6_1_6_2_ + -0.22657600000000003*count_h_top__6_2_1_1_ + -0.20475000000000002*count_h_top__6_2_2_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__6_2_3_1_ + -0.2025*count_h_top__6_2_4_1_ + -0.16402500000000003*count_h_top__6_2_5_1_ + -0.2116*count_h_top__6_2_6_1_ + 1.4*total_height__1_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__1_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__1_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__1_1_5_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__1_1_6_2_ + 1.4*total_height__1_2_5_1_ + 1.4*total_height__2_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__2_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__2_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_1_5_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_1_6_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_2_1_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_2_2_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_2_3_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_2_4_1_ + 1.4*total_height__2_2_5_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_2_6_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__2_3_1_0_ + 1.4*total_height__3_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__3_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__3_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_1_5_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_1_6_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_2_1_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_2_2_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_2_3_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_2_4_1_ + 1.4*total_height__3_2_5_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_2_6_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__3_3_1_0_ + 1.4*total_height__4_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__4_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__4_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_1_5_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_1_6_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_2_1_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_2_2_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_2_3_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_2_4_1_ + 1.4*total_height__4_2_5_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_2_6_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__4_3_1_0_ + 1.4*total_height__5_1_1_2_ + 1.4*total_height__5_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__5_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__5_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_1_5_2_ + 1.4*total_height__5_1_6_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_1_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_2_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_3_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_4_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_5_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_2_6_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__5_3_1_0_ + 1.4*total_height__6_1_2_2_ + 1.4*total_height__6_1_3_2_ + 1.4*total_height__6_1_4_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_1_5_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_1_6_2_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_2_1_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_2_2_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_2_3_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_2_4_1_ + 1.4*total_height__6_2_5_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_2_6_1_ + 1.4000000000000001*total_height__6_3_1_0_ + 0.0
SUBJECT TO
height_bottom_1_1_2_2_: - 0.476 count_h_bottom__1_1_2_2_
 + total_height__1_1_2_2_ >= 0
...


Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.10.3 
Build Date: Dec 15 2019 


Result - Optimal solution found (within gap tolerance)

Objective value:                112.91288000
Lower bound:                    112.761
Gap:                            0.00
Enumerated nodes:               130
Total iterations:               380
Time (CPU seconds):             0.09
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.09

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.09   (Wallclock seconds):       0.09

Total waste: 112.91287999999999
Solved items:
      width  height  quantity  items_bottom  items_top  prod_error
item                                                              
1     0.476   0.476       950         615.0      430.0         0.1
2     0.450   0.455      2000        1729.0       71.0        -0.1
3     0.450   0.450      2000        1800.0        0.0        -0.1
4     0.450   0.450      2000        1800.0        0.0        -0.1
5     0.405   0.405      3120        2808.0        0.0        -0.1
6     0.460   0.460      2400          57.0     2103.0        -0.1

Solved patterns:
item_bottom                  1                      2                                   3                                  4            5          6                     
count_v_bottom               1                      1          2                        2           3         2            3            3          3         1           
item_top                     2            6         2          2            6           1           1         2            1            1          1         2          6
count_v_top                  2            2         2          1            1           1           0         1            0            0          0         2          2
width_bottom          0.476000     0.476000  0.450000   0.450000     0.450000    0.450000    0.450000  0.450000     0.450000     0.405000   0.460000  0.460000   0.460000
height_bottom         0.476000     0.476000  0.455000   0.455000     0.455000    0.450000    0.450000  0.450000     0.450000     0.405000   0.460000  0.460000   0.460000
width_top             0.450000     0.460000  0.450000   0.450000     0.460000    0.476000    0.476000  0.450000     0.476000     0.476000   0.476000  0.450000   0.460000
height_top            0.455000     0.460000  0.455000   0.455000     0.460000    0.476000    0.476000  0.455000     0.476000     0.476000   0.476000  0.455000   0.460000
min_count_v_bottom    1.000000     1.000000  1.000000   1.000000     1.000000    1.000000    1.000000  1.000000     1.000000     1.000000   1.000000  1.000000   1.000000
max_count_v_bottom    2.941176     2.941176  3.111111   3.111111     3.111111    3.111111    3.111111  3.111111     3.111111     3.456790   3.043478  3.043478   3.043478
total_width_bottom    0.476000     0.476000  0.450000   0.900000     0.900000    0.900000    1.350000  0.900000     1.350000     1.215000   1.380000  0.460000   0.460000
min_count_v_top       1.431111     1.400000  1.488889   0.488889     0.478261    0.462185    0.000000  0.488889     0.000000     0.000000   0.000000  1.466667   1.434783
max_count_v_top       2.053333     2.008696  2.111111   1.111111     1.086957    1.050420    0.105042  1.111111     0.105042     0.388655   0.042017  2.088889   2.043478
total_width_top       0.900000     0.920000  0.900000   0.450000     0.460000    0.476000    0.000000  0.450000     0.000000     0.000000   0.000000  0.900000   0.920000
total_width           1.376000     1.396000  1.350000   1.350000     1.360000    1.376000    1.350000  1.350000     1.350000     1.215000   1.380000  1.360000   1.380000
width_waste           0.024000     0.004000  0.050000   0.050000     0.040000    0.024000    0.050000  0.050000     0.050000     0.185000   0.020000  0.040000   0.020000
count_h_bottom       12.000000   603.000000  1.000000  36.000000   828.000000  455.000000  296.000000  1.000000   600.000000   936.000000  12.000000  3.000000  18.000000
count_h_top          13.000000   624.000000  1.000000  36.000000   819.000000  430.000000    0.000000  1.000000     0.000000     0.000000   0.000000  3.000000  18.000000
total_height          5.915000   287.040000  0.455000  16.380000   376.740000  204.750000  133.200000  0.455000   270.000000   379.080000   5.520000  1.380000   8.280000
total_height_bottom   5.712000   287.028000  0.455000  16.380000   376.740000  204.750000  133.200000  0.450000   270.000000   379.080000   5.520000  1.380000   8.280000
total_height_top      5.915000   287.040000  0.455000  16.380000   376.740000  204.680000    0.000000  0.455000     0.000000     0.000000   0.000000  1.365000   8.280000
waste                 0.238588     1.153872  0.022750   0.819000    15.069600    4.947320    6.660000  0.027250    13.500000    70.129800   0.110400  0.068700   0.165600
total_items_bottom   12.000000   603.000000  1.000000  72.000000  1656.000000  910.000000  888.000000  2.000000  1800.000000  2808.000000  36.000000  3.000000  18.000000
total_items_top      26.000000  1248.000000  2.000000  36.000000   819.000000  430.000000    0.000000  1.000000     0.000000     0.000000   0.000000  6.000000  36.000000


I would like to express my gratitude for taking the time to work on this project. This topic is really important to me and I have been running into the wall for weeks now. I will take my time and study your solution extensively. I was digging a little bit deeper into the theory. According to one of the papers it is a mixed linear programming model which can be solved with a simple heuristic procedure based on linear relaxation. I will mark your answer as accepted if I fail to come up with a better solution in the next few weeks. Once again thank you so much for the great work and inspiration.

Thanks. I thought of one small optimisation that I just added for the 1-pattern case; I'm also going to try adding another set of bounds to see if it helps and will edit accordingly.

Additional bounds don't help so I've shown them but left them commented.
